# How to cache (store) shared_ptr with class using template?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm rewriting a class using templates. Before the code looked like below.

The change is to add a template to the bar class. However, after changing, the cache map is not working, since I could not determine the type of the actual bar class type.

Is there an easy way to fix this (e.g existing sample/coding pattern)?

Or I need to try inheritance that creates a dummy `bar_base` and store the parent `shared_ptr` and do up/down cast every time? If so, do I need to figure out template type as map key also?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

namespace foo {
  class bar {
    public:
    int m_key;
    bar(int key) : m_key(key) {}
  };
  static std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<bar>> cache;
  static std::shared_ptr<bar> create(int key) {
    if (cache.find(key) != cache.end()) {
      std::cout << "cache used" << std::endl;
      return cache[key];
    } else {
      auto p     = std::make_shared<bar>(bar(key));
      cache[key] = p;
      return p;
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  foo::create(1);
  foo::create(1);
  foo::create(1);
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT(updated):
Here is the change to be planned:

1 Add template to bar class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

namespace foo {

template <typename T = std::string>
class bar {
    public:
    int m_key;
    T   m_dummy;
    bar(int key, T var) : m_key(key), m_dummy(var) {}
};

// static std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<bar>> cache;

template <typename T = std::string>
static std::shared_ptr<bar<T>> create(int key, T var) {
    //if (cache.find(key) != cache.end()) {
        //std::cout << "cache used" << std::endl;
        //return cache[key];
    //}
    //else {
        auto p = std::make_shared<bar<T>>(bar<T>(key, var));
        //cache[key] = p;
        return p;
    //}
}
};

class mystring {
    public:
    mystring(std::string x) {

    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    auto a = foo::create<std::string>(1, "aaa");
    auto b = foo::create<std::string>(1, "bbb");
    auto c = foo::create<std::string>(1, "ccc");
    auto d = foo::create<mystring>(1,mystring("ddd"));
    return 0;
}
```

2 Adapt the cache/create map. How?

Comment: Please show what is not working and remove all irrelevant lines (the lines you can remove while still producing the error)

Comment: You say this is the old code? What about the newer code?

Comment: Which specialization of `bar`, for which type `T`, is `foo::create` supposed to create?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik idealy it shall be no limited, in my case, it could be string or string variants.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question: how is `foo::create` supposed to know which specialization of `bar` it is expected to create? What's the return type of `foo::create(1)` call? Or do you plan to modify call sites as well, in some way (and if so, how)?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, sorry I miss the create fun part, here is the update with entire code with template except for cache part. The purpose is to avoid create new bar<T> if it's already in the map. (of course, only bar with same template type can be reused)

Comment: Well then, obviously, make it `static std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<bar<T>>> cache`. You can make it a member of `bar`, or a static local variable in `create`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik using map inside bar will make it hard for my rubbish collector to clear up datas for different kind of caches(like every 5 minutes using a timer), since I don't know how many kinds of instance of templated is generated....

Comment: Well, you are now introducing new requirements that were not in the original question. New requirements would require new design, of course. In this case, it would seem you'd need some form of type erasure. If you'd like further help, you'd need to explain what it is you plan to do with this cache, beyond the code already shown. It might be best to start a new question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think I fixed the mess now, appreciate if you can review the solution.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some search on google, I found a solution, hope this can be helpful who has same requirement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <typeindex>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace foo {

class bar_base {
};
template <typename T = std::string>
class bar : public bar_base {
    public:
    int m_key;
    T   m_dummy;
    bar(int key, T var) : m_key(key), m_dummy(var) {}
};

static std::map<std::pair<std::type_index, int>, std::shared_ptr<bar_base>> cache;

template <typename T = std::string>
static std::shared_ptr<bar<T>> create(int key, T var) {
    if (cache.find(std::pair<std::type_index, int>(typeid(T), key)) != cache.end()) {
        std::cout << "cache used" << std::endl;
        return std::static_pointer_cast<bar<T>>(cache[std::pair<std::type_index, int>(typeid(T), key)]);
    }
    else {
        auto p = std::make_shared<bar<T>>(bar<T>(key, var));
        cache[std::pair<std::type_index, int>(typeid(T), key)] = p;
        return p;
    }
}
};

class mystring {
    public:
    mystring(std::string x) {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    auto a = foo::create<std::string>(1, "aaa");
    auto b = foo::create<std::wstring>(1, L"bbb");
    auto c = foo::create<std::string>(1, "ccc");
    auto d = foo::create<mystring>(1, mystring("ddd"));
    return 0;
}
```